# Using Linq to get maximum value of only duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Linq to return me all of the items in my object that have a specific property value duplicated, and the maximum value of another specific property for all of the duplicates.

My object has properties CourseInfoId which is how I want to check for duplicates and a property Priority which i want the maximum value (and lots of other properties).

I thought this would work, but it's giving me every item in the object.

```
var group = from a in r
    group a by a.CourseInfoId into b
    let maxPriority = b.Max(d => d.Priority)
    where b.Skip(1).Any()
    from c in b
    where c.Priority == maxPriority
    select c;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is group by CourseInfoId, then filter on groups that have more than 1 item which will get you all of the duplicate items. Next, you'll have to flatten out the groups again and get the maximum property value from the results.

```
var maxPriority = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.CourseInfoId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g)
    .Max(i => i.Priority);
```

EDIT: I see now that you only want to check the properties of the duplicates, not all of the items with a duplicate ID. All you have to do is skip the first item of each group in the `.SelectMany()` call:

```
var maxPriority = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.CourseInfoId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .Max(i => i.Priority);
```